# Problems extracting XML code from Word with Python

Tags: python, xml, docx, zip

I am attempting to extract the XML code from a Word document with Python. Here's the code I tried:

```
def getXml(docxFilename):
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(open(docxFilename,"rb"))
    xmlString= str(zip.read("word/document.xml"))
    return xmlString
```

I created a test document and ran the function `getXML` on it. Here's the result:

```
 b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\r\n<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="00971B91" w:rsidRPr="00971B91" w:rsidRDefault="00B52719"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Test</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:sectPr w:rsidR="00971B91" w:rsidRPr="00971B91" w:rsidSect="009C4305"><w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/><w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="708"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>'
```

There are some obvious issues. One is that the XML code begins with an "b' " and ends with an apostrophe. Second, there is a "\r\n" right after the first set of angle brackets.

My ultimate goal is to modify the XML code to create a new Word document -- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492790/how-can-i-save-an-edited-word-document-with-python) question -- but the anomalies with the extracted XML are preventing me from doing this.

Does anyone know why the extracted XML has these strange features and how I can remove them?

EDIT: I tried using the lxml module to parse this code but I only got different errors.

I created a new function `getXmlTree`:

```
from lxml import etree

def getXmlTree(xmlString):
    return etree.fromstring(xmlString)
```

I then ran the code `etree.tostring(getXmlTree(getXml("test.docx")),pretty_print=True)` and received much more sensible XML code.

The problems arise when I tried to create a new Word document. I created the following function to convert XML code into a Word document (shamelessly stolen from [here](http://virantha.com/2013/08/16/reading-and-writing-microsoft-word-docx-files-with-python/)):

```
import zipfile
from lxml import etree
import os
import tempfile
import shutil

def createNewDocx(originalDocx,xmlContent,newFilename):
    tmpDir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(open(originalDocx,"rb"))
    zip.extractall(tmpDir)
    with open(os.path.join(tmpDir,"word/document.xml"),"w") as f:
        xmlString = etree.tostring(xmlContent,pretty_print=True)
        f.write(xmlString)
    filenames = zip.namelist()
    zipCopyFilename = newFilename
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipCopyFilename,"w") as docx:
        for filename in filenames:
            docx.write(os.path.join(tmpDir,filename),filename)
    shutil.rmtree(tmpDir)
```

Before trying to create a new Word document, I wanted to see if I could create a copy of my original test document by substituting `xmlContent = getXmlTree(getXml("test.docx"))` as an argument in the above function. When I ran the code, however, I received an error message:

```
f.write(xmlString)

TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Using `f.write(str(xmlString))` instead didn't help; it created a new word document, but Word would crash if I tried to open it.

EDIT2: tried running the above code with `f.write(xmlString.decode("utf-8"))` instead, but it didn't help; Word still crashed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: that's a string!  next step could be to parse it using one of pythons many xml parsers

Comment: Try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

Comment: @dm03514 Please see the edit to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the XML is not being encoded properly. First, write the document file as binary using `"wb"` as the mode. Second, tell [`etree.tostring()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring) what the encoding is and to include the XML declaration.

```
with open(os.path.join(tmpDir, "word/document.xml"), "wb") as f:
    xmlBytes = etree.tostring(xmlContent, encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
    f.write(xmlBytes)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't follow your exact solution; instead I just replaced `xmlString= str(zip.read("word/document.xml"))` in `getXml` by `xmlString = zip.read("word/document.xml").decode("uft-8")`, which did the trick. I'm still having a few issues though, which are outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535032/problems-extracting-the-xml-from-a-word-document-in-french-with-python-illegal); I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look.